# While using pf on FreeBSD, do I need to explicitly specify both the inet and inet6 parameters?

Tags: ipv6, freebsd, ipv4, pf

Suppose I have a rule like

```
rdr on $ext_if inet proto tcp to port https -> $inf_if port $myhttps
```

This is to redirect incoming TCP packets on the https port to a specific internal IP/port. This is in prod and works fine.

Do I need a copy of this rule with `inet6` instead of `inet` to account for IPv6 packets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take it for granted that the first rule looks like in the question, you would indeed need a separate rule for `inet6` to also do the same for IPv6.

However, if the rules are otherwise identical, you could leave out the address family, and one rule would work for both.

That is, something like this:

```
rdr on $ext_if proto tcp to port https -> $inf_if port $myhttps
```